# Methods with link_to In ruby tags (ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a Ruby on Rails project, and I noticed that the `link_to` can either work with or without a `method` specified.

With the `method` specified:

```
<%= link_to "Log In", new_user_session_path, class: 'btn btn-primary navbar btn', method: :get %>
```

Without the `method` specified:

```
<%= link_to "About", about_path, class: 'navbar-brand' %>
```

How do I know when should I use a `method` with `link_to`, and when I should not?

[image]

Comment: when you need to redirect from one page to other you use link_to

Comment: You should post your source code instead of sharing an image

Comment: by default link_to has method: :get but you want to change your link_to method ,so you should specifically  define it.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, you should use method when it's different from `get`. Eg, I specify it when I need to use `post` and so on.

Comment: please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to lift your quality up

Comment: Thank For Your Help

Answer (score 0):

It tells the browser which [HTTP method](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) to use when submitting the request to the web server. Supported verbs are `:post`, `:get`, `:delete`, `:patch`, and `:put`.

You can always specify it if you want to be explicit, otherwise it's only necessary when you need it to deviate from the default. Different functions have different defaults.

- `button_to`  defaults to `:post`
- `link_to` defaults to `:get`
- etc.

This link has many examples and a more thorough explanation:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html